# Complex integration over a simple pole

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

A paper I am reading addresses the following integral:

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{F'}{F}(1+it)h(t)dt$$

where $F$ is a function of $s\in\mathbb C$ with a simple pole at $s=1$, and $h$ is a smooth, compactly supported function. I am a little confused by the integral over the point $t=0$. Should it be interpreted as an integral with some small positive rdius around $s=1$, and the limit taken as the radius goes to 0, or does the integral makes sense as it is?

p.s. The function $F(s)$ is in fact Riemann's $\zeta(s)$, of course.

Comment: Maybe they mean it in the principal value sense.  That is, $\lim_{s\to 0} \int_{|t|>s}$.

Comment: Yes, the principal value is the result you would get for $\displaystyle \lim_{\sigma \to 1^+} \int_{-\infty}^\infty F'/F(\sigma+it) h(t) dt$ which is I  suppose what you'd like to calculate

Comment: I agree with reuns and Stephen  Montgomery-Smith.  The integral is to be interpreted in the Cauchy-Principal value sense.

Comment: Thanks! It is as I thought then. But following @reuns would it be equally legitimate to use $1^+$ or $1^-$? (ignoring issues of convergence) I suppose the difference would be a sign?

Comment: I think it matters which way you go around the pole, making a difference of $2 \pi i h(0)$.  The principle value integral gives you the average of these two.